# Starting Email Intent Android, do I get an Exception?

Tags: java, android

I have a FloatActionButton that opens an Email intent, it works very well. The question is: I assume, that the User has already installed an Email App. What happens, if the user does not have an email app? Do I get an Exception or does my app crash ?

Here is the belonging code:

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Message to me", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","support@example.com", null));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose your Email Client :"));


        }
    });
```

Comment: If you did not have `Intent.createChooser()`, you would get an `ActivityNotFoundException` from `startActivity()` if `intent` does not match any activity. However, there is always a chooser, so that will not happen here, and I forget the behavior when the chooser has no options. You could test it yourself by changing the scheme temporarily to `mailtwo` or `mailtoo` or `notavalidscheme` or something, and see what happens.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see, thank you very much for your answer.